# login if not logged in in protractor test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor and have some problem with login/logoff.

I want write a helper method, that make a loggoff, if the logout button is not present. My problem is to verify, if the login button is present or not and than to react and call the login/logoff method.

If I do something like this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
element(by.id('logoutBtn').isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {
    if (!isPresent) {
        return deferred.resolve(isPresent);
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
```

I got an error that said, that the element 'logoutBtn' is not present.

Do you have any ideas to check wheter an element is present or not and than do something?

I allready found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25314348/1319755), but it doesn't realy help, because it also throws an error, that the element could not be found using the locator By.cssSelector.

Comment: Are you sure the element is present at this particular moment?

Comment: no, thats the point. I am not shure, if the element is present or not. Thats what I want to find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It was all about promises... This works:

```
var self = this;
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

expect(this.loggedIn()).toBe(true);

this.removeMessages().then(function () {
   element(by.css('#logoutBtn')).isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
       element(by.css('#logoutBtn')).click().then(function () {
           expect(self.loggedIn()).toBe(false);
           deferred.fulfill();
       });
   });
});
return deferred.promise;
```

The Problems were some thens and there is a big difference between `expect(loggedIn).toBeTruthy()`;`and`expect(loogedIn()).toBeTruthy();

The first one gives the function loggedIn to the expect clause and causes an error like `Function is not truthy`. The second returns the promise and is what I want.

Thanks for all your help...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a close paren. Try this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
element(by.id('logoutBtn')).isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {
    if (!isPresent) {
        return deferred.resolve(isPresent);
    } else {
        return deferred.reject(isPresent);
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
```

The close paren you forgot is the one right after `element(by.id('logoutBtn')`.